# When passing an array through a function, can I call the function after?

Tags: javascript

I have to save an array of integers to a variable and then use a for loop to loop through each element in the array where I pass the array into a doubling function then I save the original number and the doubled number as key-value pairs in an object. I am currently stuck and here is my code:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (i=0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    myArray[i];

}

var double = function(number)
{
   return number * 2;

};

var double = {i: double(myArray[i])};
```

Comment: It says I need 15 reputation points to upvote an answer.

Comment: You don't need 15 reputation to accept the answer, just click on the checkbox outline next to the answer you want to accept :)

Answer (score 2):

Just do a loop to initialize the object:

```
 var i = 0; 
 var doubleObject = {}; 
 for( i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++){
     doubleObject[myArray[i]] = doubleFunction(myArray[i]);
 }
```

`double` is a [reserved word](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) by the way. You should not use it.

Comment: i think OP mean `doubleObject[i] ` instead of `doubleObject[myArray[i]] `

Comment: He said : "I save the original number and the doubled number as key-value pairs".

Comment: yep, you right! i'm confused, start value for `myArray` and code with `i` that index at the end :-)

Comment: OP's original array was a bit ambiguous :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop the Array to do something with every element in the Array.

There a couple of errata in your code:

- you are doing nothing with `myArray[i];` in the loop.
- you assigning the variable `double` twice.
- `i` is not defined in the last piece of code.

A clean way to do this is:

```
var myDoubleArray = myArray.map(function(arrItem){
    return double(arrItem);
})
```

Edit:

After reading comments/question thoroughly I think Paul D. has your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

yet another variant with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
myArray.reduce(function(ac,item){
    return ac[item] = doubleFunction(item), ac;
}, {})
```